# What if user update the question completely to new one and your posted answer not relate to it?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted an answer related to the user query and after some time user changed the question completely with the new issue he was facing instead of updating the question with details.

What should do in such a case as the answer will not make any sense in such a case?

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/317448/revisions

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing an existing question in a way that invalidates existing answers is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64459/295232). Basically, you're invalidating someone else's work. They should post a new question instead (and link to the old question if appropriate).

What to do?

- Leave a comment stating that this is not appropriate, with a link to this very question, to [Rolling back a completely changed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64459/295232), [What to do when a user radically changes their own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225645/295232) or similar topics. Please do so in a constructive way; some users just aren't aware of the rules.
- If you have 2k+ reputation, you can [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/295232) the question to a previous version.
- As @SanderMangel says, you can flag the post for moderator attention. This isn't necessary per sé if you can do the rollback yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your question. It is best to flag this kind of behavior for the mods to take a look

Comment: we need to take some action against this user, as this user has done this kind of things many times in this platform, might be you know better what actions you can take as mod